# How to convert parts of a header to subscript in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, lowercase

In the following line I am having trouble with converting the number 2 in the header to subscript:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="H2O" Width="50" DataMemberBinding="{Binding SSE, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

How can i do this in xaml?

I know there is a lot of examples out there but i couldnt get anything to work in my case.

Comment: Um, what? - the number 2 in lower case? Digits don't have case.

Comment: Sorry, have no idea why and how, but i misunderstood lowercase and subscript :) What i mean is subscript and not lowercase. I have edited my question.

Comment: what is the type of `Header` property? does it allow content model?

Comment: It is of type object

Comment: @user1093774: My bad - I should have realized what you meant :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `TextBlock` in your `Header` and concatenate text from 3 element where one is `Run` with `BaselineAlignment="Subscript"`

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="50" DataMemberBinding="{Binding SSE, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            H<Run BaselineAlignment="Subscript" FontSize="10">2</Run>O
        </TextBlock>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of fuss just for &#178; but I did forget `BaselineAlignment` so that was a nifty reminder

Comment: _&#178_ shows as square not subscript (above, not below) but anyway I  simplified it

Comment: Really? I'm sitting here in a WPF proj right now looking at a subscript 2 just fine, not sure why you'd be getting a block.

Comment: Yes, I've tried your answer. Even in your answer it is aligned to top line like superscript/square, not subscript